# Have ssh-add be quiet if key already there

Tags: shell-script, ssh, ssh-agent

I want to put `ssh-add /path/to/special_key` at the top of a script. This works fine, but it *always* prompts for the passphrase. This is strange, and a little annoying, as it still asks for the passphrase even when `ssh-add -l` shows the key has already been added.

Is there a way to tell it: "add this key and ask the passphrase if not already been added, otherwise do nothing" ?

Comment: Similar question at https://superuser.com/q/325662

Comment: I wonder if it's a sort of security feature of `ssh-add`?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I don't see any options to ssh-add that help achieve your desired result, but it's pretty easy to work around this, given that you're concerned with one key in particular.

First, grab the fingerprint for your special_key:

```
ssh-keygen -lf /path/to/special_key  | awk '{print $2}'
```

Let's say this fingerprint looks like 6d:98:ed:8c:07:07:fe:57:bb:19:12:89:5a:c4:bf:25

Then, at the top of your script, use `ssh-add -l` to check whether that key is loaded, before prompting to add it:

```
ssh-add -l |grep -q 6d:98:ed:8c:07:07:fe:57:bb:19:12:89:5a:c4:bf:25 || ssh-add /path/to/special_key
```

You can fold all this together into one line if you wish:

```
ssh-add -l |grep -q `ssh-keygen -lf /path/to/special_key  | awk '{print $2}'` || ssh-add /path/to/special_key
```

Comment: The one-liner is working nicely, thanks!

Comment: I find this simplified one-liner to be a bit more comprehensible, and preferable since it avoids `ssh-keygen` (after all, I don't want to generate any keys), instead using the key path: `ssh-add -l | grep -q 'path/to/key' || ssh-add /path/to/key`

Comment: `ssh-keygen` in the answer does not generate a key - same as `ssh-add -l` in your example does not actually add anything. Flags modify the behaviour of the commands so it does not exactly match the name. Note that these versions functionally differ - if checking by path and the key at that path changes, your version would not pick it up. The version in the answer would also detect existing key no matter where it was loaded from.

Answer (score 9):

You might have particular reasons to be using `ssh-add` explicitly, but if you just want "I want to be prompted for my passphrase the first time I use the key, but not after that," openssh has a simpler solution:

Put `AddKeysToAgent yes` in your `.ssh/config` file.

Comment: Thanks. That was apparently added in ssh 7.2 (Ubuntu 18 appears to be on version 7.6).

Comment: Yup, "AddKeysToAgent isn't supported by my openssh version" is a good reason to use ssh-add explicitly ;-)

Answer (score 5):

There is no direct way to check using just `ssh-add` but you can make use of `ssh-keygen` and some scripting to check.

```
$ if  ssh-add -l | \
    grep -q "$(ssh-keygen -lf /path/to/special_key | awk '{print $2}')"; \
    then echo yes; \
    else echo no; \
  fi
```

The above would then print `yes` if the fingerprint represented by the file `/path/to/special_key` was present in `ssh-add -l`'s output.

#### Example

```
$ if  ssh-add -l | \
    grep -q "$(ssh-keygen -lf /path/to/special_key | awk '{print $2}')"; \
    then echo yes; \
    else echo no; \
  fi
yes
```

Where the contents of output from `ssh-keygen -lf /path/to/special_key` looks like this:

```
$ ssh-keygen -lf /path/to/special_key
2048 8a:6a:5a:44:20:c8:3a:da:ab:dd:1c:12:2c:e4:20:0c  dev-servers (RSA)
```

And we're using `awk '{print $2}' to select just the 2nd column, which contains the fingerprint, i.e.:

```
8a:6a:5a:44:20:c8:3a:da:ab:dd:1c:12:2c:e4:20:0c
```

#### References

- [How do I extract fingerprints from .ssh/known_hosts?](https://superuser.com/questions/529132/how-do-i-extract-fingerprints-from-ssh-known-hosts/529145#529145)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but I needed the answer today, and this was the right question. But maybe due to old key format - ssh-keygen answer variations wouldn't function for my case. Here's a variation using just the output from "ssh-add -l", which just lists out all managed keys. This will be checking if my path-to-my-key is a substring within that result. If so, all's good, otherwise add the key.

```
PATH_TO_MY_KEY="/path/to/special_key"
if [[ "$(ssh-add -l)" == *"${PATH_TO_MY_KEY}"* ]]; then 
        echo "Key is ready managed in ssh-agent "
else  
        echo "adding key for ${PATH_TO_MY_KEY} "
        ssh-add ${PATH_TO_MY_KEY} 
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

`ssh-add --apple-use-keychain FILE` worked fine for me on Mac.
It still shows "Identity added: " lines but doesn't ask for passphrase.

From man page:

> `--apple-use-keychain`      When adding identities, each passphrase will also be stored in the user's keychain.  When removing identities with `-d`, each passphrase will be removed from it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this oneliner to only ask for the passphrase and add the key to the ssh if the key is not yet added:

```
# for a private key located at "/path/to/special_key" (your specific question):
( KEY="/path/to/special_key" && ( ssh-add -T "${KEY}.pub" 2>/dev/null || ssh-add -q "$KEY" ) )

# for a private key located at ~/.ssh/id_rsa (generic/typical name):
( KEY="${HOME}/.ssh/id_rsa" && ( ssh-add -T "${KEY}.pub" 2>/dev/null || ssh-add -q "$KEY" ) )
```

Explanation:

- everything is wrapped in parantheses to not leak the custom `KEY` variable into the environment
- `... ssh-add -T "${KEY}.pub" 2>/dev/null ...`: The `-T` allows to test a specified *public* key (here: `${KEY}.pub`) against compatibility with *any* private key currently managed by the running (used/identified) *ssh-agent* (the `2>/dev/null` redirect is there for making the command quiet in the failure case).

  - if there is *no* match, the command will return a nonzero exit status, and continue with `ssh-add -q "$KEY"`.
  - if there *is* a match, the command will return a zero exit status, and early-exit the oneliner.
- if  `... ssh-add -q "$KEY"` is reached, that means the running *ssh-agent* does not manage this private key yet. Therefore this command is executed to ask for the passphrase and add the key to the agent.