# ssh-copy-id login with key to copy other key

Tags: bash, ssh

Is there the way use key login with `ssh-copy-id` to copy another key, without manually editing `~/.ssh/authorized_key`.

There seems to be `-o ssh_option` in man page, which I tried to pass the -i option which doesn't seem to work.

```bash
ssh-copy-id -o "-i ~/.ssh/working-key" -i ~/.ssh/new-key user@ip
```

Comment: i guess it does'nt work `ssh -o` seem to be different thing.

Comment: another question with a solution to this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182048/looking-for-effective-alternative-to-ssh-copy-id-which-fails-if-you-do-not-have

Answer (score 6):

The option you're looking for is [*IdentityFile*](https://manpages.debian.org/openssh-client/ssh_config.5#IdentityFile) but it won't work by default: `ssh-copy-id` which is a shell script, expects to use its `-i` parameter both for the public key to copy, and for the private key to authenticate with, as a way to detect the creation of duplicate entries (note: without `-f`, the private key counterpart must be available in addition to the public key to be copied, to be able to authenticate). But `-o IdentityFile` overriding the `-i` parameter given to `ssh` inside `ssh-copy-id` makes `ssh-copy-id` believe the key was already authorized, since it could connect without password, and give this final result:

```
$ ssh-copy-id -o 'IdentityFile=.ssh/working-key' -i .ssh/new-key.pub  user@ip
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: Source of key(s) to be installed: ".ssh/new-key.pub"
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
Enter passphrase for key '.ssh/working-key': 

/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: WARNING: All keys were skipped because they already exist on the remote system.
        (if you think this is a mistake, you may want to use -f option)
```

Adding `-f` will make it work (note: and then doesn't require the availability of the private key) because there's no check to fail. Running the command twice will not be idempotent anymore: it will add again a new identical entry in remote's `authorized_keys`.

That this has not been seen as an issue is probably because it's working well when `ssh-agent` is in use: if `working-key` is loaded in the agent (but not `new-key`), then `ssh-copy-id -i .ssh/new-key.pub  user@ip` will work as expected. Running it again will detect the duplicate.

In short:

- you should use `ssh-agent`, and load `working-key` in it,
- else you can insert `-f -o IdentifyFile=~/.ssh/working-key` but it won't detect duplicates,
- else here's a wrapper running `ssh-agent` if needed.

---

Here's a wrapper that will just do this for you: in case it didn't find an already running `ssh-agent`, it will temporarily spawn one for the single operation. If one exists it will be used (and the added key will remain added, I intend this to stay simple). It will deal very simply with the additional option: the added option (`-I`) must be first if it exists and followed by its separate parameter, feel free to improve it (probably by using some case loop). I also took the extra step to not ask the passphrase for a key already loaded in an available agent (using [this Q/A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132791/have-ssh-add-be-quiet-if-key-already-there)).

`wrapper-ssh-copy-id.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ x"$1" = x-I ]; then
    if [ $# -lt 2 ]; then
        exit 1
    fi
    privkeyfile="$2"
    shift 2

    if [ -z "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ]; then
        trap 'eval $(ssh-agent -k)' EXIT
        eval $(ssh-agent)
    fi

    fingerprint=$(ssh-keygen -lf "$privkeyfile" | awk '{print $2}')
    if [ -z "$fingerprint" ]; then
        exit 1
    fi

    ssh-add -l | grep -F -q "$fingerprint" || ssh-add "$privkeyfile"
fi

ssh-copy-id "$@"
```